# Restriction of an operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, commutator, linear-algebra

I am reading Cohen-Tannoudji's *Quantum Mechanics Vol. 1*. In problem 11 from  Chapter II there are two given operators defined in a space generated by $\{\left|u_1\right>,\left|u_2\right>,\left|u_3\right>\}$:

$H=h\omega\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&-1\end{matrix}\right) \qquad B=b\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{matrix}\right)$

**The problem is to show that these commute.** It is easy to show it with matrix multiplication. But, my question comes up because of the solution given in the book, it says the next:

> *"$\left|u_1\right>$ is an eigenvector common to H and B. We therefore have, obviously $HB\left|u_1\right>=BH\left|u_1\right>.$ We see, then, that for $H$ and  $B$ to commute, it is suficient that the restrictions of these operators to the subspace $\mathscr{E}_2$, spanned by $\left|u_2\right>$ and $\left|u_3\right>$, commute. Now, in this subspace, the matrix representing H is equal to $-h\omega I$ (where $I$ is the $2\times2$ unit matrix), which commutes with all $2\times 2$ matrices. $H$ and $B$ therefore commute."*

I need an explanation of this answer. What is the *restriction of an operator* and why is it sufficient to show that $H$ and $B$ commute if their restrictions in space $\mathscr{E}_2$ commute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space generated by $|u_1 \rangle, \, |u_2 \rangle$ and $|u_3 \rangle$ is $R^3$ itself, since they are linearly independent. Consider a subspace of $R^3$, like $R^2$ for example. We can inquire about how an operator defined in the whole space acts solely on this subspace, and for that we need only to ignore everything it does *outside* of our subspace. In your case we want to forget about what the operator does in the subspace generated by $|u_1 \rangle $, which we know that is an eigenvector of both $H $ and $B $, so we focus in the subspace complementary to it, which is the plane generated by $ |u_2 \rangle$ and $|u_3 \rangle$. We are therefore *restricting* the action of $H $ and $B $ to a subspace. On this subspace we see, by forgeting about the first line and column of $H $ and $B $, that $H $ commutes with $B$. We therefore arrive at the conclusion that $H$ and $B$ commute on a plane and the one dimensional subspace complementary to it is generated by a common eigenvector: therefore they commute in the whole $R^3$.